# Show GalleryView by intent with my own Activity is not visible

Tags: android, android-intent

I have following requirement.
When the App receives a image file from server, it should open the image automatically in default image viewer.

Normal case:

1. Activity is visible.
2. Received image file from Server.
3. App send Intent.ACTION_VIEW
4. Gallery View shows the downloaded image.

Fail case:

1. Activity is not visible. (E.g. Press Home and return to launcher.)
2. Received image file from Server.
3. App send Intent.ACTION_VIEW
4. Nothing happens. (<-- Fail)

** If I go back to my App then I can see the Gallery View.

Is there anything I can do to get the Gallery View to show even my activity is not visible?

How i start the Gallery view:

```
            final Intent openfileintent = new Intent();
            openfileintent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            final File file = sharedfile.getFileInstance();
            openfileintent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), sharedfile.getMimeType());
            startActivity(openfileintent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found answer after trial and error.

There is 2 flags to add.

And most importantly, should use application context instead of activity context.

```
        final Intent openfileintent = new Intent();
        openfileintent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        (*1) openfileintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        (*2) openfileintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        final File file = sharedfile.getFileInstance();
        openfileintent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), sharedfile.getMimeType());
        (*3) getApplicationContext().startActivity(openfileintent);
```